# Помогите! Выдает ошибку при входе в админку сайта syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in class-abstract-lite-metabox.php on line 21

Tags: php, syntax, parse

```
public $assets_url = MONSTERINSIGHTS_PLUGIN_URL . 'lite/includes/admin/user-journey/assets/';
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: ошибка явно не в этой строке

Comment: MONSTERINSIGHTS_PLUGIN_URL .

Comment: меняю на , ; выдает ошибку syntax error, unexpected ''lite/includes/admin/user-jour' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)